# What is the best practice for a GraphQL mutation in an AddToCollection scenario?

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

Say I have a book-sharing app, and given say a user with a collection of favorite books, when adding a favorite book is the most common best practice that we just use `editUser` mutation and update their collection of favorites in the user object itself, or use a named `addFavorite` mutation that just sends along the book to add?

```
type Book {
  title: String
  author: Author
}

type User {
  name: String
  address: Address
  favorites: [Book]
}
```

My opinion is that it's clearer and better to have a named mutation for `addFavorite` since it's the key use case and it's clearer to have mutations that add relationships rather than having it implied through the update of another object.

```
mutation AddFavorite($userId: ID!, $book: BookInput!) {
  addFavorite(userId: $userId, book: $book)
}
```

vs

```
mutation EditUser($userId: ID!, $input: UserInput!) {
  editUser(userId: $userId, input: $input) {
}

input UserInput {
  name: String
  address: Address
  addFavorite: [Book!]
}
```

Comment: I think Graphql was invented to help us fetch/post exact data we want. Having this principal in mind I think `AddFavorite` is more specific and its server implementation is specific too. Though even second option would be ideal too. So its just the matter of your own preference. For me I would go with first option

Comment: Assuming the user who is running the mutation is the user you want to add the favorite to then you shouldn't even pass the user's ID to the mutation - the server knows who the current user is. Agree with @Nux that the first style is preferred since it doesn't make assumptions about how the data is stored - ex: maybe at some point favorites become their own collection but the front end won't need to care.